# Angular nested controller initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have simple angular app with a Main Controller and a child controller. Maincontroller loads the login page and on successfull login, a welcome page is loaded in using the child controller. The app is simple one and is working. My issue is to set the logged in user name after successfull login.

```
.controller('mainController', function($rootScope, $location, Auth) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.loggedinUser = Auth.getActiveUser();
    console.log(">>>>>>   ", vm.loggedinUser);

    //check to see user is logged in for every request made
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
        vm.loggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn();

    });
```

My html page is simple:

```
<body ng-app="bookapp" ng-controller="mainController as main">
..
<li class="navbar-text">Hello {{ main.loggedinUser }}! >
```

Issue is that loggedinUser value is not displayed.

1) For it to work i have to initialize the loggedinUser value within the routechange listener.(moving the line to within listener works). Why is it so?

2) Also note that the console.log statement prints the real value after log in and when the welcome page is displayed. But variable value is set in main Controller during the application load itself(login page) and can only be changed through route change listener. It is not re-initialized during welcome page load.

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass an object reference to the controller or use the $watch service to evaluate the the `getActiveUser` function every digest and update the controller scope.

```js
angular.module("bookapp", []);

angular.module("bookapp").controller("mainCtrl", function(Auth) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.userData = Auth.data;
  vm.login = function() {
    Auth.data.loginTimeStamp = new Date();
    Auth.data.user = "TestUser";
  };
});

angular.module("bookapp").factory("Auth", function() {
  var data = {
    loginTimeStamp: null,
    user: null,
  };

  return {
    data: data
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="bookapp">

  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as main">
    <p>Hello {{ main.userData.user }}!</p>
    <button ng-click="main.login()">Log In</button>
  </div>


</body>
```

```js
angular.module("bookapp", []);

angular.module("bookapp").controller("mainCtrl", function($scope, Auth) {
  var vm = this;
  $scope.getUser = Auth.getActiveUser;

  vm.login = function() {
    Auth.setActiveUser("TestUser");
    debugger;
  };
  $scope.$watch(function(scope) {
    return scope.getUser();
  }, function(newValue) {
    vm.loggedinUser = newValue;
    debugger;
  });
});

angular.module("bookapp").factory("Auth", function() {
  var data = {
    loginTimeStamp: null,
    user: null,
  };

  return {
    getActiveUser: function() {
      return data.user;
    },
    setActiveUser: function(userName) {
      data.user = userName;
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="bookapp">

  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as main">
    <p>Hello {{ main.loggedinUser }}!</p>
    <button ng-click="main.login()">Log In</button>
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Will try this. But why cant a simple initlailization within the main controller work?

Comment: When you first load the application you're not logged in and loggedinUser is assigned by value. After you login the loggedinUser property is never updated. As mentioned,  you can pass a reference using an object or  add a watch on the service function return value

Comment: Ok. But why is the property not updated? Is it because i load the mainController for the login page and all further pages are loaded by child controllers? But i can print the value within the maincontroller. So should the two way binding result in the change being reflected? The maincontroller part of the html is not parsed by angular again?

Comment: You have to understand that you can assign a variable by value or by reference. The former is just a value so if the original value updates, the new variable won't be updated. All [primitive data types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) are passed by value if directly assigned. All other Object types are passed by reference and any changes to the objects themselves reflect across all variables as it is passed by reference.